# Prove or disprove: If $H$ is normal in $G$ and $H$ and $G/H$ are abelian, then $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

My counterexample I wanted to try is $D_{8}$ and its center $Z(D_{8})$. However, is $Z(D_{8})$ abelian? I am guessing it is because it is cyclic? I am not very knowledgeable with dihedral groups.

Comment: The center of a group is always abelian and your example works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply and useful insight!

Comment: An "easier" exemple : $G =S_3$, $H= A_3$